# Restricting user from performing certain action in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, action

I want user to stop performing certain action given in my model but that should be performed by admin only.

User.rb

```
def abc
     xxx
     xxx
end

def xyz
    xxx
    xxx
end
```

In the user model i want `def abc` to be performed only by admin and `def xyz` by both admin and user. Is it possible to do it? I have cancancan gem installed but that doesn't restrict that action from performming for the user.

Comment: Cancan will do the thing. Read docs thoroughly.
For instance: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separating-Abilities

Comment: You don't restrict it *in the model*. You restrict it in the controller. The model has no idea who the `current_user` is; that information only makes sense within the context of a controller. What does your controller look like? How are those model methods being triggered? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model-level authorization in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807905/model-level-authorization-in-rails)

Comment: Rather than marking this as a duplicate, I think this should currently be categorised as an XY problem. You're asking for help with the wrong solution, not with the original problem at hand.

Comment: How will the users update objects of this model?